# struggling with normalisation using map and reduce

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to do a radar chart but I have no control for the api output, so I have to turn a complicated data into some form. I'm stuck for at least half an hour.

How can I turn this raw data

```
const raw = [{
  "device_info": {
    "device_id": 123,
    "name": "iphone",
  },
  "age_data": [{
    "age_range": "0-10",
    "total_count": 15,
    "man": 6,
    "women": 9
  }, {
    "age_range": "11-20",
    "total_count": 11,
    "man": 7,
    "women": 4
  }]
}, {
  "device_info": {
    "device_id": 456,
    "name": "android",
  },
  "age_data": [{
    "age_range": "0-10",
    "total_count": 1,
    "man": 1,
    "women": 0
  }, {
    "age_range": "11-20",
    "total_count": 2,
    "man": 0,
    "women": 2
  }]
}]
```

into this

```
const data = [{
  age_group: '0-20',
  iphone: 26,
  android: 3
}, {
  age_group: '21-30',
  iphone: 0,
  android: 0
}, ];
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cqmyganr/2

This is what I have tried:

```
const age_group = raw[0].age_data.map(obj => ({
  age_group: obj.age_range
}))

const cams = raw.map(obj => ({
  device_id: obj.device_info.device_id,
  device_name: obj.device_info.name
}))

console.log(cams)

const age_group_with_cams = age_group.map(obj =>
  Object.assign({}, obj, ...cams)
)

console.log(age_group_with_cams)
```

Comment: I've added your tryings to the post

Comment: Please explain how you get from your input to your output. For example, I don't see how you get the values `iphone: 120` and `android: 110` in the `0-20` age group from your input.

Comment: added an answer, @AaditMShah you might take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading @webdeb's answer I figured that there was a better way to do what he did. Here's what I came up with:

```js
const raw = [ { device_info: { device_id: 123
                             , name: "iphone" }
              , age_data: [ { age_range: "0-10"
                            , total_count: 15
                            , man: 6
                            , women: 9 }
                          , { age_range: "11-20"
                            , total_count: 11
                            , man: 7
                            , women: 4 } ] }
            , { device_info: { device_id: 456
                             , name: "android" }
              , age_data: [ { age_range: "0-10"
                            , total_count: 1
                            , man: 1
                            , women: 0 }
                          , { age_range: "11-20"
                            , total_count: 2
                            , man: 0
                            , women: 2 } ] } ];

// First, we convert the raw data into a relation:

const relation = [], devices = {};

const toInt = x => parseInt(x, 10);

for (const { device_info: { device_id, name }, age_data } of raw) {
    devices[name] = 0; // The default total_count of every device.

    for (const { age_range, total_count, man, women } of age_data) {
        const [age_begin, age_end] = age_range.split("-").map(toInt);

        relation.push({ device_id, name
                      , age_begin, age_end
                      , total_count, man, women });
    }
}

// Next, we write a function that given an age range returns its stats:

const getAgeRange = (begin, end) =>
    relation.reduce((table, tuple) => {
        if (tuple.age_begin >= begin && tuple.age_end <= end) {
            const row = table.find(row => row.name === tuple.name);

            if (row) {
                row.total_count += tuple.total_count;
                row.man         += tuple.man;
                row.women       += tuple.women;
            } else table.push(Object.assign({}, tuple));
        } return table;
    }, []);

// Finally, we create an array of the age groups we're looking for:

const getAgeGroup = (begin, end) =>
    getAgeRange(begin, end).reduce((summary, { name, total_count }) => {
        summary[name] = total_count;
        return summary;
    }, Object.assign({ age_group: begin + "-" + end }, devices));

const data = [ getAgeGroup(0,  20)
             , getAgeGroup(21, 30) ];

console.log(data);
```

Hopefully that makes sense. I tried to stick to the [relational model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model) as closely as possible.

Comment: but there's one problem here, how can u tell the device list is only iphone and android? what if there are more devices?

Comment: Good question. I updated my answer to account for any number of devices.

Comment: One question, why you need Object assign in reduce's default param?

Comment: Two reasons. First, to create a shallow copy of `tuple`. We don't want to mutate the original `tuple`. Second, to set `age_begin` and `age_end` to `begin` and `end` respectively. This is not absolutely required and can be omitted. Actually, thinking about it it's best to omit it. Thanks for bringing this up. I'll update my answer and use the `{...tuple}` pattern to create a shallow copy instead.

Comment: Huh, rest in object destructuring isn't supported yet. I guess we'll stick with `Object.assign({}, tuple)`.

Comment: @CeciliaChan do you think this solution is less complicated?

Comment: My level is beginner, both answer is equally complicated for me haha

Answer (score 2):

OK, I would do use `reduce` because your are converting the data into another form `list-of-devices-with-age-info` => `list-of-ages-with-devices` the lists can have different lengths.

This would be my first step, map all devices to all existing ages

```
const usageByAge = raw.reduce((by_age, dev) => { 
  dev.age_data.forEach(age => {
    if (!by_age[age.age_range]) by_age[age.age_range] = {};
    by_age[age.age_range][dev.device_info.name] = age.total_count;
  })

  return by_age;
}, {})

// output, something like this:
usageByAge = {
  "0-10": { android: 123, iphone: 321 },
  "10-20": { android: 123, iphone: 321 },
}
```

From here again a reduce function, this time create a rule:

```
isGroupInBounds = (g, lo, hi) => {
  const [gl, gh] = g.split('-');
  return gl >= lo && gh <= hi;
}

["0-20", "21-30"].map(age_group => {
  const group = { age_group, iphone: 0, android: 0 };
  const [l, h] = age_group.split('-')

  Object.keys(usageByAge).forEach(inputGroup => {
    if (isGroupInBounds(inputGroup, l, h)) {
      Object.keys(usageByAge[inputGroup]).forEach(deviceName => {
         group[deviceName] += usageByAge[inputGroup][deviceName];
      })
    }
  })

  return group;
})
```

Yeeah, this s**t is really tricky, have tried it in your fiddle and it worked ;) Thank you for this exercise!

https://jsfiddle.net/cqmyganr/1/

Comment: Ah, makes a little more sense now. I still don't see how the OP got the values `iphone: 120` and `android: 110`. The values `iphone: 26` and `android: 3` make much more sense.

Comment: > can it be more readable
This is why I asked Aadit to take a look, lol

Comment: @AaditMShah edited the question, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I think I have a better solution. Writing an answer now.

Comment: Definitely, the first step can be moved after `isGroupInBounds` condition, np.

Comment: How you guys deal with this problem usually? I spend most of my time normalizing as a front end developer, i hate it coz im not good in this stuff haha.

Comment: @AaditMShah you're not coming up with a cleaner approach?

Comment: I am. Was just talking to my parents. You can accept this answer right now. I'll post mine when its done.

Comment: @webdeb I just found that you hardcoded the age group and the iphone and android, what if the data suddenly has a samsung? haha